# Adding joda-time as manageable dependency via sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-ide

I'm having trouble using joda-time in my scala project in scala-ide. I have the following line:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
```

But it causes the following error: `object joda is not a member of package org`

That's what I did:

I put these lines in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8"
```

Then I ran `reload` in my `sbt` session.

Then I ran `update` in my `sbt` session.

So what did I miss?

Comment: Did it successfully add the joda library to your sbt cache?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Did you tell scala-ide to reload the dependency jars?

Comment: Nope: `sbt run` tells me the same error -- and it has nothing to do with scala-ide. I'll try it anyway, thanks.

Comment: I have `joda-time` in my `~/.ivy2/cache`, by the way.

Comment: Are you using a mulit-project build and overriding lib dependencies in sub-projects?

Comment: Nope. One project, and my build.sbt is under PROJECT_ROOT/project.

Comment: May you have some aggressive import in your file, something like `import org._` ? Does it still fail if you do `import _root_.org.joda.time.DateTime` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sbt eclipse` fixed the thing.

But it was another issue: scala-ide ceased to find main class when trying to run any module extended from `App`. Removing `src` folder and creating it again nailed that bitch down.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete all joda-time jars from your computer, and reload the project again,
it seems that the jar is corrupted.