# object time is not a member of package org.joda

Tags: scala, sbt, curly-braces

I am learning scala follow this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/xTMNlRyvshE?t=433) with docker image hseeberger/scala-sbt

with first version of build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.2"
```

everything is OK.

this piece of code (snippet_1)

```
import org.joda.time._
var dt = new DateTime
```

got what I want.

with second version of build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq{
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.2";
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.2.1"
}
```

snippet_1 got this error

```
<console>:7: error: object time is not a member of package org.joda
       import org.joda.time._
                       ^
```

the only difference from that [tutorial](https://youtu.be/xTMNlRyvshE?t=433) is that I replaced `,` with `;` in the build.sbt as `,` causes error.

this command comes from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800456/10253483)

```
sbt eclipse
```

causes this error

```
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from /root/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/root/)
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
[error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)
[error] eclipse
[error]        ^
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
Seq{
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.2";
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.2.1"
}
```

Curly brackets mean you're passing `Seq` a single argument in the form of a code block. The value of a code block is always the value of the last line in the block - in this case, `"org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.2.1"`. The `joda-time` dependency is never added.

You can fix this by using round brackets and commas to supply multiple arguments to `Seq`:

```
Seq(
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.10.2", 
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "2.2.1"
)
```

Of particular note:

> the only difference from that tutorial is that I replaced , with ; in the build.sbt as , causes error.

`;` and `,` have entirely different meanings in Scala and are not interchangeable. If you find yourself needing to make that replacement, you should stop and check what you're doing.